# batch file that will copy files from a mapped network drive to a local drive

Tags: batch-file

I am having issues executing a batch file that will copy files from a mapped network drive to a local drive.

Here is the batch code I'm using (it's just in a low level folder at the moment as I don't wanna execute commands in a production environment until I have everything perfect).

```bat
@echo  off
cls
echo press any key to continue back up!
pause
net use \\sfiapp0\cirris
xcopy "\\sfiapp0\Cirris\SmartLight Test Reports*" "H:\Sioux Falls\PC04FPYLogs" /D/E/C/H/Y
echo backup complete
pause
```

the above commands will copy the files to H:\Sioux Falls\PC04FPYLogs when I request it to do so, it says “0 files copied” but not files copiesd over to that folder. I have the folders copied but empty I have  a permission to all Network and local files

Could you offer any further suggestions? any help is greatly appreciated  Thanks

Comment: Is the script run as the same user you have map the share? Try [robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145(v=ws.10).aspx) its much better as xcopy.

Comment: `/D:m-d-y`     Copies files changed on or after the specified date. If no date is given, copies **only those files whose  source time is newer than the destination time**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Robocopy did  not work at all, but xcopy worked. the issue it cpoied the folders I needed but with no contents (empty).I'm copying  from a nework drive to local Drive. I have all permissions and logged as a dmin.. any idea why the foders are empty?  Thank you

Comment: thank you I figured it out. it is working   appreciated your help

Answer (score 0):

```
Xcopy /D:mm-dd-yy  /I  sourcedir destinationdir
```

/D:dd-mm-yyyy Copies files based on modified date on or after the specified date. If no date is given, copies only those files whose source time is newer than the destination time.

To copy all the files in the directory ‘E:data’ that are modified on or after 1 st February 2011 to the folder ‘E:\backup‘

```
Xcopy /D:02-01-11 /I E:\data E:\backup
```

Example is taken from https://www.windows-commandline.com/xcopy-command-syntax-examples/. The date might be /D:dd-mm-yyyy as given in the linked page, probably can vary from system to system.